# Decorate by Delegation (like kotlin) in Scala

Tags: scala, kotlin, decorator

In kotlin there is '*Decorate by Delegation*' pattern. Is there a way to achieve it in an elegant way in Scala.

Here is a kotlin code example:

```
interface Doo{
    fun a(): Unit
    fun b(): Unit
}

class Goo:Doo {
    override fun a() {
        println("goo a")
    }

    override fun b() {
        println("goo b")
    }
}

class Moo(doo: Doo):Doo by doo{
    override fun b() {
        println("mooooooo")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val m = Moo(Goo())
    m.a();m.b()

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala 2, as far as I can tell, you cannot achieve this. It is however possible in Scala 3 with `export`:

```
trait Foo {
  
  def a: Int
  
  def b: String
}

trait Bar {
  
  def a: Int
}

def decorateAsFoo(bar: Bar): Foo = new Foo {
  export bar._ // export all bar methods/values/types in this Foo impl
  
  override def b: String = "decorated"
}


decorateFoo(new Bar { override def a: Int = 10 })
```

(See [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YQaNSWwSQlWDh3w9V8uWWg))

As you can see with `export` you don't even have to create a separate names `class` (though you could if you want to) nor you have to have any sort of subtyping relation between decorator and decoratee as long as the the result will have all the necessary definitions exported or implemented manually.

In Scala 2 (to my knowledge), the best you can count on is conversion of one data-type into another data type with similar schema, via libraries like [Chimney](https://scalalandio.github.io/chimney/). I am not aware though of any library making such conversion between classes that store behavior.

Comment: Uhm it is not the same thing as the kotlin derivation. It is similar but not the same. Indeed, if I create `Bar` as the extension of `Foo`, I cannot override b (in kotlin instead I could). Or I am wrong? ([scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cric96/GwLk6mpURVaQ8w5HJYrwxw/1))

Comment: You can exclude conflicting values manually ([scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sT5DXHjhTZuuvwpNv6QaOA))

Comment: The code example is a bit confusing, but using this export you can achieve at least the behavior that I want to achieve, which is very cool, bummer that it is not exist in scala2

Comment: Basically, `export` works as a dual to `import`: you can export by name: `export bar.a`, you can group exports `export bar.{ a, b }, baz.c`. rename things: `export foo.{ a => baz }`, you can use wildcards: `export bar._` (export everything from `bar`),  `export bar.{ b => _, _ }` (export all _except_ `b`). All the feature you can use in `import` to get stuff into your scope, you can use with `export` to expose stuff outside. Perhaps you didn't use `import foo.{ bar => _, _ }` before.